# Using MATLAB regression from Python

Tags: python, matlab, regression

I would like to call MATLAB logistic regression from Python. It seems that Python cannot handle the object returned by MATLAB . My code and error are below:

Code:

```
from __future__ import division
import matlab.engine
xVals = [[1,2,1],[1,3,1],[2,2,1]]
xVals = matlab.double(xVals)
yVals = matlab.double([1,0])
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
[Mdl,FitInfo] = eng.fitclinear(eng.spconvert(xVals),eng.categorical(yVals), 'learner', 'logistic''PostFitBias',true, nargout=2)
```

Error:

> ```
> [Mdl,FitInfo] = eng.fitclinear(eng.spconvert(xVals),eng.categorical(yVals), 'learner', 'logistic''PostFitBias',true, nargout=2)
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py", line 71, in __call__
>     _stderr, feval=True).result()
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/futureresult.py", line 67, in result
>     return self.__future.result(timeout)
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/fevalfuture.py", line 82, in result
>     self._result = pythonengine.getFEvalResult(self._future,self._nargout, None, out=self._out, err=self._err)
> TypeError: unsupported data type returned from MATLAB
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't like the class that matlab created.

I could run your fit function this way, leaving the results in the MATLAB workspace:

```py
eng.workspace['xVals']=xVals
eng.workspace['yVals'] = yVals
eng.eval("[Mdl, FitInfo]=fitclinear(spconvert(xVals),categorical(yVals), 'learner', 'logistic','PostFitBias',true)",nargout=0)
```

From there, it's an exercise in getting these two variables out of MATLAB, and into Python.  FitInfo converts without issue:

```py
eng.eval('FitInfo')


{'Lambda': 0.5,
 'Objective': 0.6375789538304049,
 'IterationLimit': 1000.0,
 'NumIterations': 8.0,
 'GradientNorm': 1.014275386457264e-07,
 'GradientTolerance': 1e-06,
 'RelativeChangeInBeta': 5.3806464923025154e-05,
 'BetaTolerance': 0.0001,
 'DeltaGradient': matlab.double([]),
 'DeltaGradientTolerance': matlab.double([]),
 'TerminationCode': 1.0,
 'TerminationStatus': ['Tolerance on coefficients satisfied.'],
 'History': matlab.double([]),
 'FitTime': 0.02450061,
 'Solver': ['bfgs']}
```

But one gets the `TypeError:unsupported data type returned from MATLAB` when attempting to do the same with `Mdl`.

However, you can still move the parts from Mdl one-by-one over into your python enivornment. For example,

```py
Beta = eng.eval('Mdl.Beta')
```

Or, you could get everything all at once by converting to json (text), and then decoding it in Python.  Of course, you should be careful with precision whenever going back and forth between text and numbers.

```py
import json
Mdl = json.loads(eng.eval('jsonencode(Mdl)'))
```